# What is the process of a Subclass 457 – Business (Long Stay) visa for Australia

Tags: working-visas, australia, canadian-citizens

I am Canadian. I used my working holiday visa for Australia (2 years total) and I've been out of the country for 2 years. A former employer has asked me to come back and work for him and that he would sponsor me. He doesn't really understand what that entails and neither do I. I told him I would pay for all the fee's and everything.

Someone told me that he needs to have an ad up looking for a worker for a certain amount of time in order for me to get approved to come work for him?

Where do I start this process? I really don't know what to do.

I think it's a Subclass 457 – Business (Long Stay) visa

The work is masonry/pavers/landscaping.

I'm also wondering how much it would cost for everything

Answer (score 2):

Start here: https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/457-

Basically, your employer-to-be has to register to be a "sponsor", and they can then "nominate" you for the position.